Resources to understand derivative pricing and simulation models and aggregation of risk measures
I am looking for a book or set of videos which explains theorems and models of quantitative finance and stochastic calculus required for understanding derivative pricing and simulation in a very layman and intuitive manner. The simplest according to many is the Hull book. Are there any simpler books? Asking for a friend who has just basic background in mathematics. Can someone suggest a high level pathway?

Hull is written in the simplest yet accurate way. Your friend with a mathematics background should do just fine.

If you want something more non-mathematical that explains the quant industry (as a whole) in a very intuitive manner, then try to read the book called "The Money Formula" by Paul Willmott and David Orrell. They have chapters regarding derivatives pricing, portfolio management, risk models and also career aspects of a quant. The chapters come with loads of examples and charts for better understanding. It is a good book to read in order to gain insight into the industry without being mathematical adept.
